# AJAX upload doesn't work and it reload the entrie page

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Simply this the code for PHP page the uses AJAX to upload file, but it doesn't work and I don't know why.

### edit

When I click submit it reload the entire page and jQuery doesn't retrieve the data posted 
by PHP to the iframe

```
<?php 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // Access the $_FILES global variable for this specific file being uploaded
    // and create local PHP variables from the $_FILES array of information
    $fileName = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]; // The file name
    $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder

    // Place it into your "uploads" folder mow using the move_uploaded_file() function
    $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "uploads/$fileName");

    // Check to make sure the move result is true before continuing
    if($moveResult == true) {
        echo "<div id='filename'>$fileName</div>";
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <title>Ajax File Upload</title>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                // If submit button is clicked
                $('form#upload').submit(function() {

                    $('#upload_wrapper').hide();
                    $('#loading').show();

                    // Get the uploaded file name from the iframe
                    $('#upload_target').unbind().load( function() {
                        var img = $('#upload_target').contents().find('#filename').html();

                        $('#loading').hide();

                        // Load to preview image
                        if(img) {
                            $('#preview').show();
                            $('#preview').attr('src', 'uploads/'+img);
                            $('#image_wrapper').show();
                        }
                    });
                });
            });

            function drawUploader() {
                $("#aa").append("<div id='upload_wrapper'>"+
                                "<form id='upload' name='upload' enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post' action='index.php' target='upload_target'>"+
                                "<input name='uploaded_file' type='file' size='30' id='uploaded_file'  />"+
                                "<input id='sent' name='sent' type='submit'  value='Upload' />"+
                                "</form>"+
                                "</div>"+
                                "<div id='loading' style='background:url(ajax-loader.gif) no-repeat left; height:50px; width:370px; display:none;'>"+
                                "<p style='margin-left:40px; padding-top:15px;'>Uploading File... Please wait</p>"+
                                "</div>"+
                                "<div id='image_wrapper' style='display:none;'><img id='preview' src='' /></div>");
                $("#aa").clone();
            }       
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="button" onclick="drawUploader()" value="start uplaod" />
        <div id="aa"></div>
        <iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="" style="width: 10px; height: 10px; display: none"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *`doesn't work`* is a problem description more suited to a common user like my grandmother, not to a software developer asking a programming related question where he encountered some specific programming related problem and asking for help from peer developers.

Comment: Do not EVER use the user-provided filename as a target for storing an uploaded file. Your code makes it utterly trivial for a malicious user to stomp on **ANY** file they want on your server.

Comment: @Marc B  it is just for testing

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov I have edited the question

Comment: @adham Please put like 30 seconds into formatting your code so it's actually, you know, readable. I've done it for you this time, but please do it in the future - you might get an answer that way.

Comment: to whom underestimate me, Look at the great answer blow .. don't be negative person more !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are calling [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) from the submit handler, so the form's default behaviour will be triggered, i.e. submit the form and render the response.

```
$('form#upload').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
});
```

**EDIT 1**

Added to delay registering the submit handler until *after* the form is actually on the page / in the DOM.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function drawUploader() {
            function mySubmitHandler (event) {
                // maybe not required - event.preventDefault();

                $('#upload_wrapper').hide();
                $('#loading').show();

                // Get the uploaded file name from the iframe
                $('#upload_target').unbind().load( function() {
                    var img = $('#upload_target').contents().find('#filename').html();

                    $('#loading').hide();

                    // Load to preview image
                    if(img) {
                        $('#preview').show();
                        $('#preview').attr('src', 'uploads/'+img);
                        $('#image_wrapper').show();
                    }
                });
            }

            $("#aa").append("<div id='upload_wrapper'>"+
                            "<form id='upload' name='upload' enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post' action='index.php' target='upload_target'>"+
                            "<input name='uploaded_file' type='file' size='30' id='uploaded_file'  />"+
                            "<input id='sent' name='sent' type='submit'  value='Upload' />"+
                            "</form>"+
                            "</div>"+
                            "<div id='loading' style='background:url(ajax-loader.gif) no-repeat left; height:50px; width:370px; display:none;'>"+
                            "<p style='margin-left:40px; padding-top:15px;'>Uploading File... Please wait</p>"+
                            "</div>"+
                            "<div id='image_wrapper' style='display:none;'><img id='preview' src='' /></div>");

            // If submit button is clicked
            $('form#upload').submit(mySubmitHandler);

            $("#aa").clone();
        }       
    </script>
```

Comment: Yep, to stop the browser doing it's normal `<form>` behaviour. Answer updated.

Comment: but the problem is the the browser doesn't see the submit handler at all !! so the function of submit doesn't be called !

Comment: The problem is at the time you register the `submit` handler there is no form. The form is only created when you click the button and `drawUploader()` is called. Move the registration of the submit function to *after* the form has been added to the page. Edited answer.

Comment: You are the man of the match , you are awesome thanks a lot dear, your positive responses helped me a lot, you are better than all the people above !!

Comment: Glad we got there in the end! You can also use the jQuery `live()` function to register for events on elements that don't exist yet. http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Are you sure you want to prevent the default action?  The only way to upload the file is going to be to let the form's default action happen by submitting the form and using the iframe as the target.

Comment: Yes, you're probably right. If you look at the original question it states *"When I click submit it reload the entire page"*, so that's why we started off there. I shall remove.

Comment: @Pual another awesome answer :)

Answer (score 1):

adham - the problem is that you are defining the submit function in your $(document).ready(); but you haven't actually inserted that form into the DOM yet when the .ready() event is fired.  You should move the $('form#upload').submit(function() {...}); into the "drawUploader" function *after* the form content gets inserted into the DOM.